# How can i make the margin go all the way down?

Tags: xml, odoo

I have this custom report

```
                            <thead style='border:1px solid grey;'>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:5%;" class='letra2'>
                                        <b>Nro</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:10%;" class='letra2'>
                                        <b>CODIGO</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:45%;" class='letra2'>
                                        <b>CONCEPTO</b>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width:5%;" class='letra2'>
                                        <b>UD</b>
                                    </td>
                                   
                                </tr>
......
```

How can I set the margin down like the photo

[image]

is this posible?